# How to serialize fabricjs object to store in DB ?

Tags: mysql, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I want to store fabricjs object into Database and used again to continue my editing. I mean I want to create draft facility with fabricjs editing.

Comment: fabricjs have nice  tutorials and also demos which helps you to get some basic things to work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should read fabricjs Tutorial for [#serialization](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3/#serialization) & [#deserialization](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3/#deserialization).

After serializing an object you can  store it into the database and you can load the serialized object from the database to `fabricjs` canvas.

And `fabricjs` has nice [Articles](http://fabricjs.com/articles/),[Docs](http://fabricjs.com/docs/),[Demos](http://fabricjs.com/demos/)
 to help you understand what `fabricjs` can & can't do.